Migration SSIS 2019 to 2022 : DTSPipelineWrap
I migrated my SQL Server 2019 to version 2022. I have a special package using a C# code that refers to these dll :

Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll

And this part of the code ran perfectly on SQL Server 2019:
IDTSComponentMetaData100 newComponent = _dataFlow.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
newComponent.ComponentClassID = typeof(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter).AssemblyQualifiedName;

(The goal of all the code is to create a package dynamically)
After migrating to SQL Server 2022, I changed the TargetServerVersion in the package to "SQL Server 2022", and I needed to refer the new dlls with the version 160 (for SQL Server 2022).
In short, in this version,  the new version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.dll no longer behaves the same way.
DataReaderSourceAdapter property of Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline is not recognized and I didn't find any documentation for this dll on the Microsoft site for version 2022.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to do the same thing in SQL Server 2022 ? I'm afraid Microsoft no longer supports IDTSPath100 in SQL Server 2022
